# How to deal with namespaces in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

If I have XML like this:

```
  <sample>
     <a:element1 xmlns:a="..." />
     <b:element2 xmlns:b="..." />
  </sample>
```

it seems that XSL can't find the two child nodes of `<sample>` due to the prefixes `a:` and `b:`.

If I eliminate the two prefixes as well as the namespace declaration, then they are found.

The problem is that I can't do anything about the orginal XML file. So how can I find `<element1>` and `<element2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
        xmlns:a="http://nsa"
        xmlns:b="http://nsb"
        version='1.0'
        >
<xsl:template match="sample">
  <xsl:value-of select="a:element1/@id"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="b:element2/@id"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```